# Why does setting an outbound rule with iptables block the whole site, but an egress rule in the Google Cloud firewall doesn't change much?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, web-application-firewall

I'm with a small project in GCE, and I wasn't happy with the egress charges. I searched the subject to understand it better, and according to many, every time a page is requested and then sent outside the network, it's egress. But I decided to test it and block the egress traffic by setting a firewall rule as follows:

```
Traffic: egress; Action: deny; Ip ranges: 0.0.0.0/0; Protocols and ports: all;
```

The result was: the website is still working, and only a few things stopped working, such as email and updates. But every single page can still be accessed by anyone.

Then, I did the following with iptables to see the difference:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

It blocked my website completely. I even lost access to SSH. Thank God I didn't save it, and rebooting the instance was enough.

So, I can't understand what counts as egress to Google.

Comment: 'Egress' is presumably an outbound connection as far as the firewall is concerned, not just outbound traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If a client connects to your instance (ingress - incoming connections), for example a web browser, a rule for the return traffic is automatically created and allowed. VPC firewall rules are stateful.

> When a connection is allowed through the firewall in either direction,
> return traffic matching this connection is also allowed. You cannot
> configure a firewall rule to deny associated response traffic.

The rule that you created prevents the instance from connecting to another destination (egress - outgoing connections).

[VPC firewall rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)

Comment: So the egress option is useless, right? Well Google doesn't explain that. Not even their support knows that. I talked to them today and they couldn't explain how it works, but just copy and paste the text from the Google Cloud page.

Comment: Egress rules are very useful. They control outbound traffic. For example, you could prevent a hacker from getting outside your machine if they break-in. You can prevent updates to specific servers. There are many uses for them. Most architects do not bother to configure outbound rules as you need to reverse your thinking about access/deny. Google offers private access services so that your instances do not need to access the public Internet. Egress rules can enforce that restriction.

Comment: I meant "They control outbound connections".